# Cannot find component with expression p:message

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i have this code

```
<p:tabview id="tabViewId">
<p:tab>
<h:form id="formOneId">
<h:inputText id="inputOneId">
<p:message id="msgOneId" for="inputOneId">
<!--end tags-->
</p:tab>

<p:tab>
<h:form id="formTwoId">
<h:inputText id="inputOneId">
<p:message id="msgTwoId" for="inputOneId">
<!--end tags-->
</p:tab>
```

i am using same `id` for `h:inputText` but in different `h:form` 
and i am getting below Exception

```
Cannot find component with expression "inputOneId" referenced from "tabViewId:formTwoId:msgTwoId"
```

how do i resolve this issue ??

`p:message for="inputOneId"` jsf does not find this because i have two `h:inputtext` with same `id` but i am using different containers ids.
please help

Comment: @kevcodez my question is different please read it again, i am asking about `p:message for="inputOneId"` jsf does not find this because i have two `h:inputtext` with same `id`

Comment: @kevcodez why id should be unique ?? i am using different container id then ids will be treated uniquely

Comment: You should probably go for `<p:message id="msgOneId" for=":tabViewId:formOneId:inputOneId">` which is the absolute path to the id...

Comment: @kevcodez: almost. The **second** `p:message…` should be changed to use an absolute id. Or use a PrimeFaces selector

Comment: @Kukeltje when i am using this it did not work for me e.g `<p:message id="msgTwoId" for=":#{p:component('inputOneId')}">`

Comment: After I fixed the typos and missing closing tags, I can't reproduce it with Mojarra 2.2.11 + PrimeFaces 5.2 on Tomcat 8.0.24.

Comment: @BalusC i did not understand your comment.

Comment: It works fine for me. So, problem is not visible in information provided so far, after editing the code into workable format.

Comment: @BalusC  if you dont mind,could you email me working code on mohsinazeemrind@gmail.com

Comment: Uh? Just do as if you're trying to answer this question. Create a brand new and blank project with most minimal configuration and most recent versions and smallest possible single XHTML file and copypaste the code in the question into its `<h:body>` and then fix the syntax errors caused by typos and missing closing tags and then run it.